# SQL code for finding jobs logged within +/- 1 day for the same site

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I'm trying to set up a report to show me jobs that might potentially be duplicates.
The criteria I want to use in the report is to show me all jobs for a specific job type, for a site, where there is already a job logged within +/- 1 day.

Eg a job with job_code of "G012" comes in with a date_logged of Jan 24th for West Side which has a site_code in the system of "WS1".

What I would like the system to do is to look to see if there is already a job logged with job_code of "G012" and site_code of "WS1" within a date range of +/- 1 day of the date_logged date.

code i have got so far is

```
select
job.job_number,
job.job_entry_date,
central_site.site_code,
central_site.site_name

from
job
inner join job_type on job_type.job_type_key = job.job_type_key
inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number and job.job_log_number = 
job_status_log.job_log_number
inner join job_status on job_status.status_code = job_status_log.status_code
inner join central_site on central_site.site_code = job.site_code

where
job_type.job_type_code in ('G012', 'G013') and
job_status_log.status_code = '5200'

order by central_site.site_code, job.job_entry_date
```

Sample Data so far

```
JOB NUMBER  JOB_ENTRY_DATE     DATE_LOGGED  SITE_CODE  SITE_NAME
1           24/01/2020 14:32   24/01/2020   121        HIGH STREET  
2           23/01/2020 23:23   23/01/2020   293        BLAKEMORE
3           23/01/2020 12:23   23/01/2020   224        MAIN STREET
4           23/01/2020 15:23   23/01/2020   121        HIGH STREET
```

What I would like it to show

```
JOB NUMBER  JOB_ENTRY_DATE     DATE_LOGGED  SITE_CODE  SITE_NAME    DUPLICATE
1           24/01/2020 14:32   24/01/2020   121        HIGH STREET  YES
2           23/01/2020 23:23   23/01/2020   293        BLAKEMORE    NO
3           23/01/2020 12:23   23/01/2020   224        MAIN STREET  NO
4           23/01/2020 15:23   23/01/2020   121        HIGH STREET  YES
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, if you can simplify the logic to focus just on what you want, that would help.  Although those joins don't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Try something like `count(*) over (partition by site_code order by date_logged range between 1 preceding and 1 following)`

Comment: How would I add this "count (*)" to the existing code?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question; see if it helps. It checks every site code's *previous* and *next* date and - if the difference is less than 1 day, consider it a duplicate.

```
SQL> with test (job_number, date_logged, site_code, site_name) as
  2    (select 1, date '2020-01-24', 121, 'high street' from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '2020-01-23', 293, 'blackemore'  from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2020-01-23', 224, 'main street' from dual union all
  5     select 4, date '2020-01-23', 121, 'high street' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select job_number, site_code, date_logged, site_name,
  9       lag(date_logged) over (partition by site_code order by date_logged) prev_date_lged,
 10       lead(date_logged) over (partition by site_code order by date_logged) next_date_lged,
 11       --
 12       date_logged - lag(date_logged) over (partition by site_code order by date_logged) diffp,
 13       date_logged - lead(date_logged) over (partition by site_code order by date_logged) diffn
 14     from test
 15    )
 16  select job_number, date_logged, site_code, site_name,
 17    case when abs(diffp) <= 1 or abs(diffn) <= 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end duplicate
 18  from temp
 19  order by job_number;

JOB_NUMBER DATE_LOGGE  SITE_CODE SITE_NAME   DUP
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---
         1 24/01/2020        121 high street yes
         2 23/01/2020        293 blackemore  no
         3 23/01/2020        224 main street no
         4 23/01/2020        121 high street yes

SQL>
```